# Matplotlib legend in increasing order

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have text files named as 5.txt, 10.txt, 15.txt, 20.txt but when I read the files with glob module and use fname variable in the legend I get disorganized legend data.

```
for fname in glob("*.txt"):

    potential, current_density = np.genfromtxt(fname, unpack=True)
    current_density = current_density*1e6
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.get_yaxis().get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)
    plt.plot(potential,current_density, label=fname[0:-4])

plt.legend(loc=4,prop={'size':12}, 
           ncol=1, shadow=True, fancybox=True,
           title = "Scan rate (mV/s)")
```

[image]

How can I plot and give the corresponding label to the data with in increasing order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1 (Recommended)**

You will need to sort and display the legend yourself. [`plt.legend`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.legend) takes a list of lines and a list of strings as the first two optional positional arguments. You can maintain a list of the items you need, sort it into the order you want, and pass the portions you want over to `legend`.

```
ax = plt.gca()
legend_items = []
for fname in glob("*.txt"):
    potential, current_density = np.genfromtxt(fname, unpack=True)
    current_density *= 1e6
    line, = ax.plot(potential, current_density)
    name = fname[0:-4]
    legend_items.append((int(name), line, name))

legend_items.sort()
ax.get_yaxis().get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)
ax.legend([x[1] for x in legend_items], [x[2] for x in legend_items],
          loc=4, prop={'size':12},  ncol=1, shadow=True,
          fancybox=True, title = "Scan rate (mV/s)")
```

Major additions are marked in **bold**, while minor style changes that can probably be ignored are marked in *italics*.

Major additions include the accumulation of the items for the legend. I use tuples for each item because a list of tuples is automatically sorted by the first element first. The comma in `line, = ax.plot...` is necessary because it triggers argument unpacking on the list that `plot` returns. An alternative would be to do `line = ax.plot(...)[0]`. The file name is no longer added as an explicit label to the data.

Among the minor changes, I switched to using `ax.plot` and `ax.legend` instead of `plt.plot` and `plt.legend`. This is the object oriented part of Matplotlib's API and it makes things a little clearer. Also, you don't have to keep calling `gca()` to get the reference over and over this way. Also, `set_useoffset` only needs to be called only once, not inside the loop.

**Method 2**

Another way to approach the problem would be to pre-sort the file names before processing them, so that they appear in the correct order in your legend:

```
import os
file_list = os.listdir('.')
file_list = [x for x in file_list if x.endswith('.txt')]
file_list.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[0:-4]))
for fname in file_list:
    ...
```

You will have to do the name filtering yourself, but it is not especially difficult. The sorting key is just the number. Also, you will note that I got tired of doing the custom fancy formatting for this update :)

Answer (score 6):

Just to provide yet another method, which does not require to change anything in the plotting part of the script:

```
handles, labels = plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()
handles, labels = zip(*[ (handles[i], labels[i]) for i in sorted(range(len(handles)), key=lambda k: list(map(int,labels))[k])] )
plt.legend(handles, labels, loc=4, ...)
```

Comment: Very nice. I was trying to avoid having to explain the transpose operation you have on the second line, but I'm glad to see an answer that has it for completeness. Also, if you would consider breaking up that monster one liner into three operations (transpose, sort, transpose), the sort key would be much more legible.

Comment: I was actually trying to get it all in one line, but that didn't work well. ;-) It's actually more for fun. In a real world application I would have chosen a method similar to your method 1.

Comment: You can get it down to one line if you call `get_legend_handles_labels` four times (to get `handles` and `labels` separately) and use star expansion on the transpose: `plt.legend(*zip(*[ (plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()[0][i], plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()[1][i]) for i in sorted(range(len(plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()[0])), key=lambda k: list(map(int,plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()[1]))[k])] ), loc=4, ...)`. Enjoy!

Answer (score -1):

Dont know if this is so relevant but I ended up here anyway - I found I didnt need the middle line - If you want 2 columns this worked for me;

```
handles, labels = plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()
plt.legend(handles, labels, loc=4,
       ncol=2, shadow=True, title="Legend", fancybox=True)
```

Comment: Why is this about sorting legend items? You're just making the legend box a two-column box.